# multiple process unlinking share memory, need that shared memory should be unlink only when all process exit

Tags: shared-libraries, ipc, shared-memory

I am writing a shared library which provide read/write functionality to its reader and writer processes.
Reader or Writer process can start in any order and can stop anytime and then can restart.

To achieve above scenario for both process i opened the share memory as `O_CREATE:
g_shmfd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);`

Now whenever one process goes down, if i `shm_unlink`, then next time new share memory object is opened which i dont want. 
If i have closed the fd which resolve above issue but the share memory is never destroyed by this workaround.
What is the best way to achieve that multiple process always open a share memory object which is already opened and should destroy it only when all process `shm_unlink` it, not just single process calling `shm_unlink` destroying the object and next time `shm_open` creates a new share memory object.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `O_EXCL` flag in [shm_open()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) along with `O_CREAT` to check if shared memory object is already exists. If it already exists shm_open will fail with return code `EEXIST`

`EEXIST:` Both O_CREAT and O_EXCL were specified to `shm_open()` and the
              shared memory object specified by *name* already exists.

Comment: thanks, what i am looking for is that when one process exits and calls shm_unlink it destroy shm object but it should only be destroyed when all processes have exits.